# Rails PayPal proof of concept

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm trying to create an ultra simple paypal custom integration with rails. I'm following [Ryan Bates Railscast #141](http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics) on this subject and I've simplified it even further. If you have experience with super simple paypal integration, any advice would be appreciated!

I'm attempting to pass **everything** through my account model. A proof-of-concept.

```
def paypal_url(return_url)
  values = {
    :business => 'jwade_1268181180_biz@gmail.com',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_url,
    :invoice => 2,
    :amount => 7,
    :item_name => 'Membership',
    :item_number => 1,
    :quantity => 1 
  }

  "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

and of course I create a link:

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", @account.paypal_url(accounts_path) %>
```

The Paypal detects an error: "**Your shopping cart is empty**", which is strange because I can see everything my model passes in the URL:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?amount=7&business=jwade_1268181180_biz@gmail.com&cmd=_cart&invoice=&item_name=Barcoden+Membership&item_number=1&quantity=1&return=/accounts&upload=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer we need to have a closer look at your code.

But perhaps this can help you: [A Testable PayPal IPN with Rails 2.3](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/02/23/a-testable-paypal-ipn-with-rails-23)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that following the railscast results in that empty cart error message.
Try creating a form  to replace the link like:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' do %>
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Your sandbox biz Account"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Some Name"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="100"> 
  <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
  <% end %>
</div>
```

That will work. Looks that the cart is not created unless you use a post request.

Using `:method => :post` in the `link_to` helper will not work.

You can use the [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) helper to create a mini form and replace the link_to in the railcast.